# Laravel Defining Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relationships, table-relationships

I have one table named `Content` which is a master table like

`Content : id content_name created_at updated_at`

and another table `Course` like

`Course table have many content_id`

`Course : id content_id course_name created_at updated_at`

I have created relation like this.

`Content Model`

```
class Content extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'contents';
    protected $guarded = array('id');

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Course');
    }
}
```

`Course Model`

```
class Course extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'courses';
    protected $guarded = array('id');


    public function content()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Content');
    }
}
```

When i am fething the data like this
`$courses=Course::find(1)->content;`

It throws error like

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'contents.course_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `contents` where `contents`.`course_id` = 1)

I am unable to rectify the problem in relations as I am new to laravel.

Comment: Why does `course` belong to `Course` and `content` has many `Content`?

Comment: so what would be the probable solution for it :( Please help me bro

Comment: Do you have course_id column in contents table in your database?

Comment: no in content table there is only these fields (id content_name created_at updated_at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, but you have your relationships backwards. The table that has the foreign key is the one that belongsTo the other one. In this case, your `course` table has the foreign key `content_id`, therefore `Course` belongs to `Content`, and `Content` has one or many `Course`s.

```
class Content extends Eloquent {
    public function course() {
        return $this->hasMany('Course');
    }
}

class Course extends Eloquent {
    public function content() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Content');
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers! your answer saves my time!

Answer (score 0):

in your migrations(create_courses_table) , make sure to set the **foreign key** like that ,

```
$table->integer('content_id)->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('content_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('contents')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your table design, maybe it should be something like this.

Taking your statement: "**Course table have many content_id**". I perceive that you are saying that 1 course can have multiple content, is that right? If yes, you might want to change your table design to something like below

```
Course
======
id
course_name
created_at 
updated_at

Content
=======
id
course_id (set this as FK)
content_name 
created_at 
updated_at
```

migration code for content

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('content', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('content_name');
    });

    Schema::table('content',function($table)
    {
        $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('course')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Then in your model

```
class Course extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'course';

    public function content()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('content', 'course_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Content extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'content';

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('course', 'course_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Then to access your data via eager loading

```
$course = Course::with('content')->get();
```

OR

```
$content = Content::with('course')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about determining associations. Your associations should be:

**Content**
Content has many courses

```
class Content extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'contents';
    protected $guarded = array('id');

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Course');
    }
}
```

Course

The course belongs to content.

```
class Course extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'courses';
    protected $guarded = array('id');


    public function content()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Content');
    }
}
```

So you can do query association.
For finding content -> courses:

```
$courses = Content::find(1)->courses;
```

For finding course -> content:

```
$content = Course::find(1)->content;
```